Discard extra record once 100 % coverage achieved
I have ObjectA of type List with value

  

  Public class ObjectA {
    double start;
    double end;
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap();
    @NonNull Object objectB;
}


now we have List with different value
start = 0.0, end 0.5 ,properties = {}, objectB 
start =0.5, end 0.9, properties = {}, object B
start = 0.1, end 0.7 , properties = {}, object C

now my requirement is to return true if ObjectA has interval covers at least 85 % match else return false so I written as

     private double getContinuousMatchedCoverage(final XYZ xyz) {
                List<ObjectA> objectAs = xyz.getObject();
                objectAs.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Ob::getStart));
                change.setObjectAs(objectAs);
        
                double continuousSegmentLength = 0.0;
                double prevStart =xyz.getObjectAs().get(0).getStart();
                double prevEnd =xyz.getObjectAs().get(0).getEnd();
        
        
                for (int i = 1; i <objectAs.size(); i++) {
                   ObjectA objA = objectAs.get(i);
                    double start = objA.getStart();
                    double end = objA.getEnd();
        
                    if (start <= prevEnd) {
                        // Overlapping or continuous segments
                        prevEnd = Math.max(prevEnd, end);
                    } else {
                        // No overlap, finalize the current segment
                        continuousSegmentLength += (prevEnd - prevStart);
                        prevStart = start;
                        prevEnd = end;
                    }
                }
               return continuousSegmentLength + (prevEnd - prevStart);
    }


now my requirement is discard the extra entry in ObjectAs list  more than 85% coverage. E.x. these two entry is contribute to more than 85 % coverage.
start = 0.0, end 0.5 ,properties = {}, objectB 
start =0.5, end 0.9, properties = {}, object B

hence third entry is extra.
start = 0.1, end 0.7 , properties = {}, object C

I want to discard this in ObjectAs list . How can I achieve this?
